# PHP Debugging Tools - File Root is Different With the URL Path

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I work on a website that `index.php` initially loads several configurations to define specific classes for their respected URLs. For example, a URL at `http://localhost/page/1/` loads a PHP class at `http://localhost/website/sys/scripts/new/page.php`. My question is how to configure the NetBeans IDE for PHP so that it debugs the `http://localhost/page/1/` instead of `http://localhost/website/sys/scripts/new/page.php` whenever trying to debug the `page.php` file? Would you recommend a better tool for debugging such system?
Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't use NetBeans IDE (but I used to many years ago) and to achieve this you need to provide the IDE with some sort of path mapping from server path `/page/1/` to local path `website/sys/scripts/new/page.php`. How to set up the mapping is described here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#debug_url